# Slash is lost from url with the php header function

Tags: php, html

I am using this redirect:

```
header("Location: http://mywebsite.com/preface");
exit();
```

But it always redirects to

```
http://www.mywebsite.compreface/
```

preface is preface.php.

Why?

Comment: Is the header string being built by string concatenation, or did you literally type it in?

Comment: Open the network tab on your browser and see what headers are being sent. PHP doesn't magically remove slahes, there is probably another (bad) redirect somewhere.

Comment: I smell a badly crafted .htaccess